# Apache Tomcat Configuration - One Apache Server and Multiple Tomcat Sites

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I'm facing one issue while configuring apache web server for multiple tomcat sites. 
Here's my requirement : 
1. Apache webserver - Single Instance  
2. Same application(WebApps) across 3 different multiple tomcat instances  
The front end server and app server all hosted on single server(Solaris)

When I access Apache server with a particular site name, It should pick up the apps only from that tomcat site

I tried various options while going through different sites on google but unfortunately no option resolved this issue as of now..

My Current Modification in vhost conf file and workers.properties (Apache Server) and server.xml on app server are as below.

```
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.com
  DocumentRoot /opt/htdocs/test-1.xxx.com/docs

  ServerName x.x.x.x
  ServerAlias test1-1.xxx.com

:
:
:
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.com
  DocumentRoot /opt/htdocs/test-2.xxx.com/docs

  ServerName x.x.x.x
  ServerAlias test1-2.xxx.com

:
:
:
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@xxx.com
  DocumentRoot /opt/htdocs/test-3.xxx.com/docs
  ServerName x.x.x.x
  ServerAlias test1-3.xxx.com

:
:
:
</VirtualHost>
```

Worker.properties

```
worker.list=tomcat1,tomcat2,tomcat3

worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.host=test1-1.xxx.com
worker.tomcat1.port=8009



worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat2.host=test1-2.xxx.com
worker.tomcat2.port=48009


worker.tomcat3.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat3.host=test1-3.xxx.com
worker.tomcat3.port=58009
```

Server.xml - The port numbers are different for each instance as mentioned in workers.properties.Here what I've modified on each tomcat instance in server.xml
in terms of host name. *Please assume that all the port no.s are different for all 3 tomcat instances*

tomcat-1

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="test1-1.com" jvmRoute="tomcat1">
<Host name="test1-1.com"  appBase="webapps"  
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="test1-2.com" jvmRoute="tomcat2">
<Host name="test1-2.com"  appBase="webapps"  
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="test1-3.com" jvmRoute="tomcat3">
<Host name="test1-3.com"  appBase="webapps"  
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

The problem is that, every time when I launch any tomcat site, every time it's picking up the webapp from first tomcat server i.e. test1-1.com

e.g. 
If I open, http://test1-***2***/home/index then though the site is opening but it's picking up the webapps directory from "test1-1.com" site..

My requirement is that - When I open http://test1-***2***/home/index, it should pick up the webapps which is hosted on tomcat site-2 i.e. test1-2.com

Please let me know, what's wrong I'm doing here .. Feel free to ask me if you need any more info

Unfortunately I can not use mod_jk module as all my webapps directory structure  are same across all 3 tomcat instances - so pattern matching is not possible

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using nginx instead of apache. It's easier to configure and probably more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to complete this assignment with loads of changes across multiple servers. 
Actually above configuration was right only except 'NameVirtualHost' tag was missing in vhost config file and some configuration on CMS from where it was fetching contents..

--Cheers--

Answer (score 0):

Your virtualhost config is missing the JKMount option to tell apache which worker should be used to serve the content: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/mod_jk-howto.html

You can also use apache ProxyPass to achieve almost the same result. In your situation, jkmount is a better option because if you have multiple tomcat serving the same application, it's easier to create a configuration to load balance traffic and guarantee HA.

About the apache config I suggest you the following:

1. change `<VirtualHost x.x.x.x:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:80>` so apache is listening on any interface, port 80. (Tell apache to work on nameBased VirtualHost instead of ipBased)
2. I see your `ServerName x.x.x.x` is the same in every virtualhost: this does not work. ServerName and ServerAlias should be unique in your configuration or, if i recall correctly, the first one read by apache will match and the others will be ignored.